# How to set default DATE when creating table in mysql 8.0.32?

Tags: mysql, date, default, create-table

I am trying to create a table with a column with a DATE type. I would like to set the default value for this field to be CURRENT_DATE.
This does not work as expected, especially when compared to doing the same thing with a TIMESTAMP.

This is the problem:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE expenses (expense_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CURRENT_DATE)' at line 1
```

Whereas doing the exact same thing with timestamp works fine:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE expenses (expense_timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

Both current_date and current_timestamp function as expected outside of table creation:

```
mysql> select current_date;
+--------------+
| current_date |
+--------------+
| 2023-03-20   |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select current_timestamp;
+---------------------+
| current_timestamp   |
+---------------------+
| 2023-03-20 01:33:27 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.32    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I think this must be a bug in MySQL 8.0.32; I cannot find a way to set the default date to the current date.

I am trying to create a table with a DATE column and have it set the default value to the current_date, but this does not work.

I have also tried changing the column to a TEXT type and this also doesn't work.
I have tried `CREATE TABLE expenses (expense_date DATE DEFAULT CAST(CURRENT_DATE, DATE);`

I can't get the current date to be set as the default in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> **Explicit Default Handling as of MySQL 8.0.13** The default value specified in a DEFAULT clause can be a literal constant or an
> expression. With one exception, enclose expression default values
> within parentheses to distinguish them from literal constant default
> values.

Since `CURRENT_DATE` is just a synonym for `CURDATE()` it's an expression, so

```
CREATE TABLE expenses (expense_date DATE DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE));
```

works just fine. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/piXEi5b69uFemSR2xzk2DK/0

Note that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is the one exception referred to above, and the enclosing parentheses are not required, so

```
CREATE TABLE expenses (expense_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

also works.

Answer (score 1):

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with date works just fine.

Just insert some values and see.

```
[temp]> CREATE TABLE expenses (expense_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.042 sec)

 [temp]> show create table expenses;                                     +----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table    | Create Table                                                                                                       |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| expenses | CREATE TABLE `expenses` (
  `expense_date` date DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: Maybe on your version of MySQL that works, but not on 8.0.32:


`mysql> CREATE TABLE test (expense_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);`
`ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'expense_date'`

Comment: Try add () as in response above